# map<K, V> to a sorted list with each object has attributes K, V (V in reverse sorted order)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have `map<K, V>` already built up, after I sorting the `V` in reverse order.

How could I using the sorted list to create a list `<Type>` object with the attributes `K, V` ?

Specifically, I want the objects' Vs in the list in sorted order. The following doesn't deliver my expected result.

```
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
   for (int i = 0; i < weightedAves.length; i++) {
       if (map.get(key) == weightedAves[i]) {                   
               Rating rating = new Rating(key, weightedAves[i]);
               MovieRatings.add(rating);
       }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more info about datatypes here?  Is MovieRatings a List?  It appears that weightedAves is a String[] ... you probably want to do a .equals() instead == in that if statement.

Comment: Hey Steve! sorry for the confusion! weightedAves is an already sorted double type list based on map's values,  MovieRatings is the list I wanna create, with each object (Class type:Rating) has the attributes of map's K and V.

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Hey Aominè! Sure, basically I wanna get each movie's weighed average ratings from the highest to the lowest, so the map key is movieID, the Values are their corresponding weighted average rating. My task is to create a list of movie collections, with each movie has movieID and its weighted average rating. After I was trying to create a list using this code, and print each item's attributes, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I would suggest using TreeMap implementation of Map, with values as key, then probably you need not use a comparator.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to make use of Streams.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .forEach(e -> movieRatings.add(
        new Rating(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
    ));
```

Otherwise, you can simple add to the List in any order and sort the List after added the items.

```
map.forEach((key, val) -> {
    movieRatings.add(new Rating(key, val));
});
movieRatings.sort(...);
```

You can specify how you would like the order arranged by creating a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to handle how to order the data.